# The argument type 'void Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String)?'

Tags: flutter

I want to pass a function in my constructor and want to use in next. I also used VoidCallback instead of Function but the same error showing....
"The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()'"

````
  ```  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyTextField({Key? key, required this.label,required this.onChanged}) : super(key: 
   key);
  final String label;
  final VoidCallback onChanged;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      onChanged: onChanged,
      decoration:  InputDecoration(
        hintText: label,
        hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
        border: const OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
        ),
        enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide:
          BorderSide(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent, width: 1.0),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
        ),
        focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide:
          BorderSide(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent, width: 2.0),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
````

Answer (score 0):

instead

```
final VoidCallback onChanged;
```

use

```
   ValueChanged<String>? onChanged;
```

e.g

```
class MyTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyTextField({Key? key, required this.label,required this.onChanged}) : super(key: 
   key);
  final String label;
  final ValueChanged<String>? onChanged;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      onChanged: onChanged,
      decoration:  InputDecoration(
        hintText: label,
        hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
        border: const OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
        ),
        enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide:
          BorderSide(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent, width: 1.0),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
        ),
        focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide:
          BorderSide(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent, width: 2.0),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: //I followed your guide and then this happened where i reuse MyTextField:                              error: A value of type 'Null' can't be assigned to a parameter of type 'void Function(String)' in a const constructor. (const_constructor_param_type_mismatch at [gup_shup] lib\screens\login_screen.dart:33)                                                               MyTextField(
              label: 'Enter your email',
              onChanged: (String value) {  },
            ),

Comment: try to make optional i.e ValueChanged<String>? onChanged; check the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

because VoidCallback not the same type as Type of onChanged in text filed so

change

> final VoidCallback onChanged;

to

> final  void Function(String)? onChanged;